# Formula inside formula

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I recently started VBA programming. But I am facing a problem

```
VLOOKUP(E1,tcl!A:C,3,False)
```

I want E1 dynamically. When Raw number 1, we put formula VLOOKUP(E1,tcl!A:C,3,False). When Raw number 2 , we put formula VLOOKUP(E2,tcl!A:C,3,False). When Raw number 3 , we put formula VLOOKUP(E3,tcl!A:C,3,False).......
We know we can get Raw number by **=RAW()** I want something like **VLOOKUP(E+=RAW(),tcl!A:C,3,False)**.

Then it will execute like: `Raw1:**VLOOKUP(E1,tcl!A:C,3,False)**, Raw2:**VLOOKUP(E1,tcl!A:C,3,False)** etc.`

Can anyone tell me how to write this formula?

Comment: Look into absolute and relative referencing. Your problem is solved by the correct use of the $ sign. There is no trace of VBA in your question but if your problem somehow relates to VBA you would need to work on your question to establish such a relationship. More detail of how E1 came into the code would be needed.

Comment: Can you please tell how can I write dynamically? Because E+=RAW() is not appropriate.

Comment: Use `INDEX` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Please run this code in a workbook where a worksheet by the name of "TCL" exists. While you do so, another worksheet must be active in which you have different values in E1:E5 that you want to look up in TCL!A:C.

```
Private Sub Try_Looping()

    Dim Rng     As Range            ' lookup range
    Dim R       As Long             ' loop counter: rows
    
    Set Rng = Worksheets("tcl").Range("A:C")
    For R = 1 To 5
        On Error Resume Next        ' skip over look-up error
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(R, "E").Value, Rng, 3, False)
        If Err.Number Then
            MsgBox "Look-up of """ & Cells(R, "E").Value & _
                   """ taken from " & Cells(R, "E").Address(0, 0) & _
                   " in range " & Rng.Address & " failed."
        End If
    Next R
End Sub
```

The procedure demonstrates how you can change the lookup value's row source dynamically in a loop using VBA.

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I already solved it almost same way !